# How do I integrate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute $$
\int \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} dx
$$

I am not sure how to do this one. I need some suggestions please. By the way, I need to integrate this for homework.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried something, what are some of the known techniques you posses?

Comment: I multiplied it by its conjugate, but that just makes it more complicated.

Comment: Note that "plz" is not a real word in English, but rather a short for "Platz" in German, I believe. Try to stick to *actual* words next time.

Answer (score 9):

rewrite it as 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1 + x^2}{1-x^2} &= -1 + \frac{2}{1 - x^2}\\
    &= -1 + \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{1 + x}\\
\end{align*}
I'm sure, you can integrate this.

Comment: How did you manage to rewrite it that way? (-1 + 2/(1-x)) I mean, what did you think?

Comment: nevermind just a regular polinomial division =(